# Move popup window

Tags: python, squish

The popup Image window blocks the stop button and other buttons in windows application. How do I move the window in Squish? I tried to move the window using the following script. Squish is not recognizing the popup window.

```
win = waitForObject(":_Image0")

mousePress(win.x, win.y - 10, MouseButton.LeftButton, 0)
mouseMove(win.x + 100, win.y)
mouseRelease(MouseButton.LeftButton)
```

Thanks
PG

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [`mouseDrag()`](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/6.0/rgs-windowsobjectapi.html#win-mouseDrag-function) function, e.g.

```
mouseDrag(win, 100, 0)
```

In the upcoming Squish 6.1 release, there's also a [`ToplevelWindow` API](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/6.1/rgs-squish.html#rgss-toplevelwindow-object) which can be used to move such windows.